# How to limit the rows on remote/linked server

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, linked-server

I have a linked server that I have to fetch data from.  I'm joining on a table that I expect very few rows from.  The query is below, and seems to be returning all of the rows to the original server to do the sort there.

I'm looking for a way to tell the query to filter on the target machine, with a query hint or something else.

Query

```
INSERT INTO #DealerHierarchy(DealerId, Level)
SELECT cd.ParentId, cd.Level
FROM [dbo].[AssignedDealer] ad 
JOIN [nlsdb].[nls].[dbo].[vw_parentDealers] cd ON cd.RootId = ad.DealerId
WHERE ad.UserId = @userId 
AND ad.IsActive = 1
AND (@DealerId IS NULL OR ad.DealerId = @DealerId)
```

When I add the following line, it seems to change and only send back the needed rows

```
and cd.RootId = 72311
```

I have tried moving out the local query into a separate temp table, and then select from the view `WHERE DealerId IN (select from temp table)` but it still runs slowly.  Adding the REMOTE hint in the JOIN also does nothing.

Query plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1iazaaFZ

Slow code executed on linked server

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=7
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 numeric(10)',N'SELECT "Tbl1007"."ParentId" "Col1010","Tbl1007"."Level" "Col1011" FROM "nls"."dbo"."vw_parentDealers" "Tbl1007" WHERE @P1="Tbl1007"."RootId"',72311
select @p1
```

Fast code executed on linked server

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=10
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,NULL,N'SELECT "Tbl1007"."ParentId" "Col1010","Tbl1007"."Level" "Col1011" FROM "nls"."dbo"."vw_parentDealers" "Tbl1007" WHERE "Tbl1007"."RootId"=(72311.)'
select @p1
```

Comment: I believe Set RowCount = 25 will accomplish what you are after.  Do this before you run your query.   (Set back to 0 to return all)

Comment: @JayWheeler It's possible for the query to return more than 25 rows, in which case that solution seems like it would cause data integrity issues

Comment: @JayWheeler Also, that seemed to have no effect on the performance.  It still took 450ms to run

Comment: I'm reading that ROWCOUNT no longer works on INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE statements, regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a specific query to be run on the remote database by using `OPENQUERY`.  `OPENQUERY` doesn't accept a parameter, so you can make it dynamic by further wrapping it in `EXEC`.

Example

```
DECLARE @SearchString NVARCHAR = ...
DECLARE @OpenQueryString NVARCHAR = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(remotedb, ''' + @SearchString + ''')'
EXEC (@OpenQueryString)
```